# How to perform a function in SQL using a value from a subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

I am working with citibike info from bigquery, and am currently learning about subqueries. I am averaging the number of bikes available for each station, and then trying to subtract the number available at every station from the average (to get the difference).

My code looks as follows:

```
SELECT 
    name,  
    station_id,  
    num_bikes_available,  
    (num_bikes_available) - (AvailableAverage) AS Difference,  
    (SELECT AVG(num_bikes_available) 
     FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations`) AS AvailableAverage,
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations` 
ORDER BY 
    num_bikes_available DESC;
```

Before, my query looked like this:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    station_id,
    num_bikes_available,
    (SELECT AVG(num_bikes_available) 
     FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations`) AS AvailableAverage,
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations`
ORDER BY 
    num_bikes_available DESC;
```

and it ran fine.

Now it's saying it doesn't recognize the alias `AvailableAverage` and I don't know why.

I tried ordering the query so the subquery came before the difference line, and it still wouldn't recognize it (it doesn't seem like order is important here).

Do I not understand subqueries? Or is it the aliasing part?

Comment: This might not be the case, but you have a tailing comma. I don't know if BigQuery ignores that

Comment: Alias that was set in Select statement is not available within that Select statement! So, when you calculate Difference - that alias is not knows yet to the engine

Comment: and just to confirm  - trailing comma in Select list is Ok with BigQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comments for 'Why'

Meantime, below is quick, simple "fix"

```
SELECT 
    name,  
    station_id,  
    num_bikes_available,  
    num_bikes_available - AvailableAverage AS Difference,  
    AvailableAverage,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations` ,
(SELECT AVG(num_bikes_available)  AS AvailableAverage
     FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations`)
ORDER BY num_bikes_available DESC;
```